# how to connect flutter desktop app to mysql database?

Tags: mysql, flutter, localhost, flutter-desktop, local-database

am trying to build an flutter standalone desktop application which should use local database
for storing and manipulating data.

how can i achieve this result?

i have used [mysql_utils](https://pub.dev/packages/mysql_utils) package, but some developers say that its not good to directly
manipulating data without apis.

any methods without using apis are also accepted..

i've researched and got to know that you could connect to local mysql database by creating apis using php, can you show a process step by step? am intermediate at flutter app developement but new to php and mysql.

Answer (score 0):

use [galileo_sqljocky5](https://pub.dev/packages/galileo_sqljocky5) and follow [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70677635/how-to-make-local-mysql-connection-open-at-the-start-of-computerwindows) to directly access local mysql database. its working very well.