# how to make local mysql connection open at the start of computer(windows)?

Tags: mysql, localhost, windows-services, mysql-workbench, flutter-desktop

am trying to create an standalone desktop application in flutter which uses mysql as local database.

my problem is  when i need to use database from my application i need to open mysql command line client and enter my password to start service( or open connection).

**In simple term whenever i open my desktop application mysql should be ready to use. how can i achieve this?**

I have tried [starting mysql as windows service](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.7/en/windows-start-service.html) . Is it the answer which i should follow?

I followed it. But it didn't work for me..

Answer (score 0):

during installation of mysql in windows you'll get the option to start mysql as windows service. if you don't get you can follow [starting myswl as windows service](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.7/en/windows-start-service.html).

after this step open mysql installer-community from searchbar.

1. Look for "MySQL server" and click on Reconfigure
2. Click on "Next" until you reach the "Authentification Method" page

3. 

[image]

4. On the "Authentification Method" page check the second option "Use Legacy Authentication Method"
5. Then follow the steps given by the Windows installer until the end.

now you could directly connect to database and perform actions without creating it's local instance or without  even opening mysql command line client or workbench.